# How to solve (cid:x) pdfplumber python text extraction

Tags: python, pypdf, pdftotext, pdfplumber

[PDF_Doc](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O2JvMWakhkGoF0pcfG91BmnAL7VsCE17/view?usp=sharing)

I've been working with the pdfplumber library to extract text from pdf documents and it's been fine, however in the documents I'm working on now, I just get spaces and lots of (cid:x) instead of text. Any solution?
Thanks

```
with pdfplumber.open(fatura) as pdf:
    lista_paginas = pdf.pages

    fatura_individual = ''
    for pagina in lista_paginas[:len(lista_paginas)]:
        fatura_individual += pagina.extract_text()
```

```
       
(cid:12)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0),(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0),(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0),(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0),(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0),(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0),(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0),(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0),(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0),(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0),(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0),(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0),(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:0)(cid:16)
```

Just want to extract the full text

Comment: We can't really help without an example PDF.

Comment: Hi, MattDMo, i've just update the PDF file

Comment: Sorry,but I am little newby , where I put the line of code that you told? Thanks

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway, hope someone could find a way.

Answer (score 0):

Try PyPDF2 : https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-text.html

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
for page in reader.pages:
    print(page.extract_text())
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, i already try that library it works, however I have a warning ->
incorrect startxref pointer(1) , i have search but don't found information about,  what's the problem, what could happen? Thanks

Comment: The pdf is broken, but PyPDF2 can deal with it. It just let's you know. https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/suppress-warnings.html

Comment: So you say I can trust in the text extracted, just ingore de warning, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "trust"? For pdf, no library can give you a guarantee that you get for every food what you expect. But PyPDF2 recently became pretty good in text extraction

Answer (score 0):

We changed from PyPDF2 to pdfplumber because PyPDF was having problems with some documents.  We combined a function from this error page - https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber/issues/29

```
text_str = '(cid:66)'
if 'cid' in text_str.lower():
    text_str = text_str.strip('(')
    text_str = text_str.strip(')')
    ascii_num = text_str.split(':')[-1]
    ascii_num = int(ascii_num)
    text_val = chr(ascii_num)  # 66 = 'B' in ascii
```

and came up with this function; you may need to adjust it for your specific needs because we add page breaks, but the key to the function is the prune_text() function:

```
import re
import pdfplumber

def process_pdf_file_without_images(file_path):

    def prune_text(text):

        def replace_cid(match):
            ascii_num = int(match.group(1))
            try:
                return chr(ascii_num)
            except:
                return ''  # In case of conversion failure, return empty string

        # Regular expression to find all (cid:x) patterns
        cid_pattern = re.compile(r'\(cid:(\d+)\)')
        pruned_text = re.sub(cid_pattern, replace_cid, text)
        return pruned_text

    with pdfplumber.open(file_path) as pdf:
        content = ""
        for page_number, page in enumerate(pdf.pages, start=1):
            content += f"Page {page_number} Start:\n"
            page_text = page.extract_text(x_tolerance=3, y_tolerance=3)
            if page_text:
                pruned_text = prune_text(page_text)
            else:
                pruned_text = ""
            content += pruned_text
            content += f"\nPage {page_number} End:\n"
        return content
```